# PHP header( "Location: /404.php", true, 404 ) does not work

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404

I'd like to use the following to redirect pages that are no longer present in the database to the custom 404 page:

```
ob_start();
....
if ( !$found ):
  header( "Location: /404.php", true, 404 );
  exit();
endif;
```

But this actually does not redirect, but just shows an empty page (because of the exit() call before any output to the browser).

I've also tried the following:

```
if ( !$found ):
  header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" );
  exit();
endif;
```

With a 'ErrorDocument 404 /404.php' in my .htaccess file, but this also just shows an empty page.

And if I do this:

```
if ( !$found ):
  header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" );
  header( "Location: /404.php" );
  exit();
endif;
```

It does redirect, but with a 302 header.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A redirect is by definition a 302 header code which results in a new request. A 404 should NOT redirect anywhere - it's an end-of-the-line code. Instead of redirecting, simply do a `include('404.php')`.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I went with the header("HTTP\1.1 404 Not Found") followed by an include of the 404 page. Learning something new every day :-)

Comment: you should select an answer by picking it

Comment: HTTP/1.1 not HTTP\1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tried and make sure to check error_log file that is correct way is send 404 headers and then include error page to next line.

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
include 'search.php'; // or 404.php whatever you want...
exit();
?>
```

Finally you have to use exit() for text based browsers.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's a old issue but I just found it handy:

php set status header to 404 and add a refresh to correct page, like a 2 seconds after.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header("Refresh:0; url=search.php");
```

Then you have the 404 page showing up a few second before redirecting to fx search page.

In my case, Symfony2, with a exception listener:

```
$request  = $event->getRequest();
$hostname = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
$response->setStatusCode(404);
$response->setContent('<html>404, page not found</html>');
$response->headers->set('Refresh', '2;url='.$hostname.'/#!/404');
```

time ( 2) can be 0.2 if you wish very short time.

Answer (score 8):

You can't have an header 404 with a Location:

You should display the error page and set a `meta refresh` with the new url if you want to redirect

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is because of the output buffering you're starting, or because you can't redirect with a 404.  The first code example shows the output buffer starting but exiting instead of cleaning the output buffer and stopping output buffering.

Change the first example to:

```
if (!$found) {
  ob_end_clean();
  header('Location: /404.php');
  exit();
}
```

Comment: ob_end_clean(); <-- Exactly what I wanted to say. Although there isn't really a need to use ob_start() at all?

Comment: The redirect does work if I remove the 404, like so: header( "Location: /404.php", true ). It's just that I want a 404 header to be sent to the browser and this isn't the case if I do that (a 302 header is sent in that case).

Answer (score -7):

Maybe without redirect?

```
if ( !$found ):
   include('../404.php');
   exit();
endif;
```

Comment: "endif;" Really? please use if() { }, just for future reference

Comment: Yes, that actually would work (I've forgotten to mention that I've tried this as well), but the 404.php page then gives a bunch of errors because of certain include files and I'd have to rewrite a lot of the code for this page. But if nothing else works, I'll try this option. Thanks for the suggestion.